# Is it possible to create a CodedUI test project if you don't have Visual Studio Enterprise?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I would like to automate my winforms testing using CodedUI but it seems that it is only available on Visual Studio Enterprise. Is it possible to create a CodedUI test project if you don't have Visual Studio Enterprise? If not, what are the alternatives to CodedUI?

Comment: TestStack.White https://github.com/TestStack/White

Answer (score 1):

The answer as far I know is no. You need Enterprise license to use that feature. This post seems to have some more information [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369236/automation-testing-tool-for-regression-testing-of-desktop-application)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes if you are on VS 2012-2013. There you need just Premium. Enterprise version is only relevant to VS 2015.

[Here is the list of all requirements.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742(v=vs.140).aspx)