# CodedUI tests without VS Enterprise/Ultimate Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Do we need Visual Studio Ultimate (2012/2013) or VS Enterprise Edition (2015) to create CodedUI tests? I see an option to create CodedUI tests without UIMap object. Does it means that I can use Visual Studio professional edition to create CodedUI tests?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172373/is-it-possible-to-create-a-codedui-test-project-if-you-dont-have-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know answer is no. You need have Enterprise license/VS Premium/Ultimate in case of 2010/2012 to use that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio 2013 Premium to write CodedUI tests.